# If the ID of 2 components are the same, how to add the suffix to the first ID as _first and _second for the 2nd ID using XSL

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

If the ID of 2 COMPONENT IS the same, I want to add the suffix to the first ID as `_first` and `_second` for the 2nd ID using XSL. When I am trying to fetch the 2nd ID of COMPONENT, both the 1st and 2nd ID are getting fetched.

This is a sample XML

```xml
<xml>
    <root>
        <SERVCAT CREATE-DATE="05/24/2016 04:45:40" LAST-MOD-DATE="05/24/2016 04:45:40" ID="G801" TITLE="801-Starting">
            <CONFIGITEM CREATE-DATE="05/11/2016 17:09:34" LAST-MOD-DATE="05/11/2016 17:09:34" ID="G801_000" TITLE="000-G801_000_000_F_000000_202">
                <SERVICEITEM CREATE-DATE="05/11/2016 17:09:34" LAST-MOD-DATE="05/11/2016 17:09:34" ID="G801_000_F" TITLE="F-Diagnostics by function">
                    <COMPONENT CREATE-DATE="05/24/2016 04:45:40" LAST-MOD-DATE="05/24/2016 04:45:40" ID="G801_000_000_F" TITLE="G801_000_000_F-Starting">
                    </COMPONENT>
                </SERVICEITEM>
            </CONFIGITEM>
            <CONFIGITEM CREATE-DATE="05/11/2016 17:09:34" LAST-MOD-DATE="05/11/2016 17:09:34" ID="G801_000" TITLE="000-G801_000_000_F_000000_203">
                <SERVICEITEM CREATE-DATE="05/11/2016 17:09:34" LAST-MOD-DATE="05/11/2016 17:09:34" ID="G801_000_F" TITLE="F-Diagnostics by function">
                    <COMPONENT CREATE-DATE="05/24/2016 04:45:40" LAST-MOD-DATE="05/24/2016 04:45:40" ID="G801_000_000_F" TITLE="G801_000_000_F-Starting">
                        </COMPONENT>
                </SERVICEITEM>
            </CONFIGITEM>
        </SERVCAT>
    </root>
</xml>
```

This is a sample XSL

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="componentsList" select="//COMPONENT"/>
    <xsl:template match="COMPONENT">
        <xsl:variable name="myComponentIdPHX" select="@ID"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(count($componentsList[@ID=$myComponentIdPHX])=1)">
                <COMPONENT CREATE-DATE="{@CREATE-DATE}" LAST-MOD-DATE="{@LAST-MOD-DATE}" ID="{@ID}" ID2="{@ID}_first" TITLE="{@TITLE}" >
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </COMPONENT>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="(count($componentsList[@ID=$myComponentIdPHX])=2)">
                <COMPONENT CREATE-DATE="{@CREATE-DATE}" LAST-MOD-DATE="{@LAST-MOD-DATE}" ID="{@ID}" ID2="{@ID}_second" TITLE="{@TITLE}" >
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </COMPONENT>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <COMPONENT CREATE-DATE="{@CREATE-DATE}" LAST-MOD-DATE="{@LAST-MOD-DATE}" ID="{@ID}" ID2="{@ID}_others" TITLE="{@TITLE}" >
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </COMPONENT>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>   
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You'll need to add a root node, if you want a well formed XML output.

```
<xsl:key name="myKey" match="COMPONENT" use="@ID"/>

<xsl:template match="COMPONENT">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@CREATE-DATE" mode="add"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@LAST-MOD-DATE" mode="add"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@ID" mode="add"/>

      <xsl:attribute name="id2">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="count(key('myKey',@ID)) = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('myKey',@ID)[1])">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@ID, '_first')"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('myKey',@ID)[2])">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@ID, '_second')"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@ID, '_others')"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="@TITLE" mode="add"/>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="add"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="add">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="add"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, it should work fine i believe. I have to test this solution in other downstream system.

Comment: Sure, your welcome.  On this website, click the up arrow on an answer to accept it.  So, the person that helped you gets a few points.  Otherwise, good luck with the XSLT!

Comment: I need one more help!...forgot to mention the important scenario. i want to append _first, _second to ID2 attribute only when both "COMPONENT" has same ID attribute value. If the both "COMPONENT" ID attribute value is different then ID2 attribute will be same ID attribute no need to append anything. please help me out on this

Comment: I checked and it is not working as expected. It is appending _first, _second to ID2 attribute for every COMPONENT but it should appending _first, _second to ID2 only when two COMPONENT has the same ID attribute value as mentioned in my comments above. Need help

Comment: if we are not adding  **<COMPONENT CREATE-DATE="{@CREATE-DATE}" LAST-MOD-DATE="{@LAST-MOD-DATE}" ID="{@ID}" ID2="{@ID}" TITLE="{@TITLE}" >
                    <xsl:apply-templates />** inside when condition it is getting failed in our downstream system and even if i add the above COMPONENT element inside when condition then also it is failing with this code. Any how  **<COMPONENT CREATE-DATE="{@CREATE-DATE}" LAST-MOD-DATE="{@LAST-MOD-DATE}" ID="{@ID}" ID2="{@ID}_others" TITLE="{@TITLE}" >
                    <xsl:apply-templates />**  should be handled in the code provided,

Comment: Please refer to my sample xsl for when condition actually our downstream system works in that format. only we need to check is if two COMPONENT has the same ID attribute value then i should be able to change then ID2 attribute value for 1st & 2nd COMPONENT KEEPING THE similar format as mine. NEED help

Comment: In regard to "I need one more help":  The code is working as described. Are you looking at the ID in the component element?  (You shouldn't be looking at the ID in the CONFIGITEM or  SERVICEITEM elements)

Comment: In regard to "if we are not adding":  I modified the code to show you how to put the attributes in the order that you want them.  This may be what's breaking things down stream.

Comment: Also note in my original answer I said, if you want your xml to be well formed, you need to have a root node.  Not having well formed XML may be breaking your code downstream.  So, I updated my code to show you how to do that.  But, it's just meant to show you how.  You have to figure out what you want the root to be, if you want it at all.

Comment: Thanx for your reply, i will figure out where is the issue but my question is still unanswered, i want to append _first, _second to ID2 attribute only when both "COMPONENT" has same ID attribute value. If the both "COMPONENT" ID attribute value is different then ID2 attribute will be same ID attribute no need to append anything, this is the specific scenario to be solved, need help on this particular scenario. There are many instance where 4 COMPONENT has the same ID attribute value then all 4 COMPONENT to be differentiated by appending some value to ID2 attribute value, this scenario is must

Comment: So, I made a minor change to my answer.  That should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanx alot for the help